# Dockerized Laravel app is slow on Windows

Tags: laravel, docker, optimization

So i've Dockerized my Laravel app and noticed it's loading pages so slow.
But the thing is when i try to run same project on Linux it's fast. How can i optimize my Laravel app?

Here is my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM php:7.2.2-fpm
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev openssl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mcrypt mbstring
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mcrypt mbstring
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: Please add the dockerfile or configuration that you are using for this. Also is it only for pages that uses db connection or all pages including static pages?

Comment: Do you mean `Dockerfile` in my project folder? Also it's slow with pages that connects to db yes.

Comment: Yes dockerfile of your project except if you are using sails. By this "...is it only for pages that uses db connection" I wanted to know whether it's related to queries or not

Comment: @RavishaHesh i've edited the post and pages a related with some queries. But the thing is when i try to run same project on Linux it's fast.

Comment: try something like laradock which comes with nginx instead of artisan server. I guess "..on Linux" means running on linux machine. in that case it's faster because php can use the entire available RAM instead of default 250mb allocated per container by docker

Comment: I have Linux vm and Windows base machine. I swapped project `Dockerfile` with `nginx` one and still same deal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228069/discussion-between-ravisha-hesh-and-yarkinbey).